# How to export desired items of a list to excel

Tags: list, export

I have a list of feedback data. I want to export items date wise. When I click on "Export to Excel" button all the items of the list gets exported. But I want to export items of a particular date only. For example items posted from 26th June to 28th June.

Please suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a temporary list view before an export and choose to only show list items that were created between the days of your choice.

An example to filter out the items would be to only show items when 'created' is greater than or equal to [Today]-3 **and** 'created' is less than or equal to [Today]-1 as it's the 29th june today. Then the view should only return items created on your desired dates (in this case 26th and 28th june). When the list view is chosen, you can export to excel and get your desired results.

[image]